# How to build protobuf-csharp-port on Mono under Windows

Tags: c#, windows, mono, protocol-buffers

I've read the instruction for building [protobuf-csharp-port](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/) using `Mono` under `Linux/Unix` system. I still can't get it work and eventually I'll open a thread to ask why, but that's not the question of this post.

I'm using `Windows` to develop and I have successfully built protobuf-csharp-port using `VS2010`. The fact is that I need to use the generated C# classes from inside `Unity3D`, which requires to use Mono.

I have **Mono 2.8** installed on my machine.

The question is:

is possible to build `protobuf-csharp-port` in Windows using `MonoDevelop`? I tried to simply import the VS2010 solution and compile it using Mono but it doesn't works.

How can I do it?

EDIT

While trying to simply compile VS solution using MonoDevelop I got several errors. The first is in the following line of `FieldMappingAttribute.cs`:

```
 public MappedType MappedType { get; private set; }
```

The error is the following:

> FieldMappingAttribute.cs(40,40): Error CS0501:
>   'Google.ProtocolBuffers.Descriptors.FieldMappingAttribute.MappedType.get'
>   must declare a body because it is not marked abstract or extern
>   (CS0501) (ProtocolBuffers)

Comment: That error sounds like you're using a C# 2 compiler. You should use at least a C# 3 compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to build the main protobuf-csharp-port project yourself... or if you do, you should be able to do that very rarely.

You *don't* need to rebuild protobuf-csharp-port just to build the generated C# classes. Just add a reference to Google.ProtocolBuffers.dll, and you should be fine.

That said, I haven't tested it on Mono for a while. It doesn't do anything *desperately* tricky, but you should definitely test thoroughly.

Comment: so I can reference dll built using VS2010 from inside a Mono project?

Comment: @Heisenbug: Absolutely. That's the point of .NET assemblies being portable :) (In fact, with Noda Time, I've seen issues when running a mono-built assembly, which were fixed by running the VS-built assembly.)

Comment: oh wow.. I didn't realize that. So I think I use your VS2010 project and simply link the dlls.

Comment: @Heisenbug: Yes, exactly. Always use the pre-built binaries when you can :)

Comment: just the last question. I still have this error while trying to compile it under Unity3d. error CS0400: The type or namespace name `Google' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?). I add the reference to Google.ProtocolBuffers.dll. Did I have to add some other dlls references?

Comment: @Heisenbug: No, that should be all you need - but it sounds like it hasn't really added the reference properly...